# Why ajax cannot return data to element in table td?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I'm doing dependent dropdownlist.

The code work if `<select>` is not in table td.

But if the select tag are in table td, ajax will cannot return to element in table td. How could I fix this?

```
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Country:</label><br/>
        <select name="country" id="country-list" onChange="getState(this.value);">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <?php
        foreach($results as $country) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["name"]; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
        <label>State:</label><br/>
        <select name="state" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox">
        <option value="">Select State</option>
        </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>


<script>
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_state.php",
    data:'country_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#state-list").html(data);
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

in get_state.php  page

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["country_id"])) {
    $query ="SELECT * FROM states WHERE countryID = '" . $_POST["country_id"] . "'";
    $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
    <option value="">Select State</option>
<?php
    foreach($results as $state) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $state["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $state["name"]; ?></option>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where the `<select>` tag is inside table td?

Comment: ok I show it already

Comment: You should empty your `state-list` before populate it. did you properly append option list before send it to client ?? you can check resultant data by `print_r(data)` on your controller side and then call `die()` to see data list. e.g `print_r(data); die();`

Comment: OK I found it  I just have duplicate id in other area of page

Comment: Sounds great. @doflamingo

Answer (score 1):

You code appears working. Without knowing your data, it is impossible to say what's wrong. Copy this snippet and try to reproduce your problem  by entering your actual state data.

```js
/// fake jQuery.ajax
function $ajax(params) {
  params.success('<option value="1">S1</option><option value="2">S2</option><option value="3">S3</option><option value="4">S4</option>');
}

function getState(val) {
    $ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_state.php",
    data:'country_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#state-list").html(data);
    }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
     <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Country:</label><br/>
        <select name="country" id="country-list" onChange="getState(this.value);">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <option value="1">Country 1</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
        <label>State:</label><br/>
        <select name="state" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox">
        <option value="">Select State</option>
        </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: OK I found it I just have duplicate id  in other area of page my bad.